# How do I scale and rotate around different points in Libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, rotation, coordinates, scale

I'm using a `SpriteBatcher` to rotate and scale a `TextureRegion` in libGDX. I'd like to rotate the texture around an origin outside of the region, but have the texture scaled around the region's center.

As far as I'm aware, this has to be performed in one action in the `SpriteBatcher.draw()` method. The region is scaled to the correct size, but scaled away from the origin.

I could compensate by adjusting the origin location, but is there a better method?

Comment: [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49350/xna-spritebatch-draw-with-rotation-scaling-and-origin?rq=1) is about XNA rather than Libgdx, but perhaps useful? I'm not familiar with Libgdx, but does the `.draw()` method take other possibly helpful parameters?

Comment: Translate, rotate + scale, translate back, as described in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, @Anko, but that answer doesn't seem to cover scaling, which is causing the issue for me. I think it'll be simple enough to calculate the distance adjustment, it just seems that there should be a simpler method, maybe a way to transform the texture before drawing?

Comment: @JoshPetrie - I'm not sure I'd consider this a duplicate, I think that's partly due to the edit that's been made to my question's title. I asked specifically about scaling AND rotating. With libGDX there doesn't appear to be a way to perform multiple translations before a draw occurs, which means both the scale and the rotate are based on a single origin. I'd like to use a different origin for each transformation.

Comment: The same theory applies though; the answers would be the same. You can translate-rotate-translate-back. Then you can translate-scale-translate-back. The core idea is "translate, do a thing, translate back."

Comment: @JoshPetrie from my understanding libGDX doesn't give you the opportunity to perform multiple translations. I understand the theory, just not how I'd apply that to the libGDX way of working. I'd really appreciate it if this question could remain open to help me out.

Comment: [It has linear algebra functionality](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/LinearAlgebra) (and even if it didn't you could implement it yourself). Use that to compose a series of transforms into a single matrix for application in the API. If you need help with that, that probably warrants a separate question (or finding another duplicate, which probably exists for that topic).